# Instantiate objects in a list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to write a simple "point painting" code.

I have created a script which was supposed to instantiate gameobject (point) according to mouse position, but there is a  5 clone instead of 1, in a one mouse click.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Vector3 newPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        newPos.z = 0;
        Instantiate(prefab, newPos, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

[image]

how can I play with instantiate speed in  update method?

or

how can I make list (ArrayList)  of instantiated objects and then destroy objects (points) which has a same position?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that u are using `Input.GetMouseButton(0)` which will return true in every frame while the left mouse button is held down(your machine basically is so fast that while you as a human only did a simple mouse press, your computer actually rendered 5 frames thus the 5 instatiation), in order to prevent this use `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)`, which will only return true in one frame specifically when the left mouse button is pressed.

Here are the mouse button events that might be useful for you:

> Returns true during the frame the user pressed the given mouse button.
> `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(int button);`
>
> Returns whether the given mouse button is held down or not.
> `Input.GetMouseButton(int button);`
>
> Returns true during the frame the user releases the given mouse button.
> `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(int button);`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: Paint when the mouse cursor travels a certain amount of distance, like so:

```
public class MyPainter : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField, Tooltip("The prefab to paint")]
    private GameObject toPaint;

    [SerializeField, Tooltip("How far does the cursor have to move in order to paint the next object?")]
    private float paintDistanceThreshold;

    private bool isPainting;

    /// <summary>
    /// How much distance did the cursor travelled since last paint.
    /// </summary>
    private float cursorDistanceTravelledSinceLastPaint;

    private Vector2 lastCursorPosition;

    private Camera mainCameraRef;

    private void Awake() {
        isPainting = false;
        // Btw, cache the main camera. Repeated calls to 'Camera.main' is expensive.
        mainCameraRef = Camera.main;

        cursorDistanceTravelledSinceLastPaint = 0f;
    }

    private void Update() {
        // Mouse button pressed, start painting.
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            PaintAtCurrentCursorPosition();
            isPainting = true;
        }

        if (isPainting) {
            cursorDistanceTravelledSinceLastPaint += Vector2.Distance(Input.mousePosition, lastCursorPosition);

            if (cursorDistanceTravelledSinceLastPaint >= paintDistanceThreshold) {
                PaintAtCurrentCursorPosition();
            }
        }

        // Mouse button lifted, stop painting.
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
            isPainting = false;
        }

        lastCursorPosition = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    private void PaintAtCurrentCursorPosition() {
        Vector3 newPos = mainCameraRef.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        newPos.z = 0;
        Instantiate(toPaint, newPos, Quaternion.identity);

        cursorDistanceTravelledSinceLastPaint = 0f;
    }
}
```

Basically, it starts painting `OnMouseDown`.
When the mouse cursor travels a certain amount of distance (`paintDistanceThreshold`), it will paint another object.

Stops painting `OnMouseUp`.

Though one issue you might encounter is that when your mouse cursor intercepts a point where you have painted before, it will paint on that point again.

> can I make list (ArrayList) of instantiated objects and then destroy objects (points) which has a same position?

It will mostly work if your painter is pixel/grid based. Otherwise, the coordinates needs to be rounded off for it to work accurately.

That said, most painting applications today uses pixel-based. I would highly suggest that you make your painter paint by pixel/grid rather than world coordinates.
This way, you can avoid a lot of the issues that I mentioned earlier.